# Excel embedding through OneDrive: preview is correct, while the end result is not

Tags: html, excel, iframe, onedrive, embedding

I have embedded an Excel file (<2Mb) to my website using the following code generated using OneDrive.

```
<iframe width="1150" height="1300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://1drv.ms/x/c/8d06bfc014a24e6f/IQMWRn035ZjpSYXJqNaciXhFAfXO7kfIhooSmKGnNnu0xbo?AllowTyping=True&wdHideGridlines=True&wdHideHeaders=True&wdInConfigurator=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>
```

As you can see, the option allowing users to type into cells is activated.

Surprisingly, the preview in OneDrive worked as expected, but the result was dissatisfying. After the embedding, [the integrated sheet is unresponsive to my attempts to change blue cells](https://www.smartdataproducts.com/home-5144-6665).

In addition, if you click on the "view full document" button (lower right corner), it opens as a view-only document without any editing allowed. This worries me less, but I need users to be able to change blue cells.